# Calling functions into another function and using its variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def func1():
    x = 100
    john = 'hello'
    return x, john

def func2():
    func1()
    y = x
    return y

print(func2())
```

So this returns an error:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Can someone explain how to use variables of func1 in func2, and explain how calling func1 in func2 work.

Comment: You cannot use x in func2 because it is only available in func1(). Whatever variable you define locally in a function will never be accessible to another. X would have to be a static variable to be used in other functions. Define x outside of any function.

Answer (score 1):

```
def func1():
    x = 100
    john = 'hello'
    return x, john

def func2():
    x, john = func1()
    y = x
    return y

print(func2())
```

`x` is local to func1 (so as to `john`). But it is one of the returned values of the function; so use it!

Answer (score 1):

```
def func1():
    x = 100
    john = 'hello'
    return x, john

def func2():
    x,john=func1()
    y = x
    return y

print(func2())
```

If you are returning two variables from func1 then the result of func1 should be passed to some other variables too. So you should add:

```
x,john=func1()
```